# C# Web Application Tuning : PerformWaitCallback

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling, profile, dottrace

I am using dotTrace Performance 4.5 to profile a .NET 3.5 C# web application. When I record one "user request" (load of page), I see 11 threads with approximately the same timing, 7644 ms.

- **Most of the thread descriptions only contain:** 100% [Native or optimized code] - 7644 ms
- **One says:** 100% `Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebServer.WebServerApp.Main(String[])`
- **Last one reads:**

  - 86% `System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object)`
  - 14% `PerformWaitCallback` (1094 ms) >> 12% = `ProcessRequest`

Can you tell me:

- Why are there so many threads? (images resources, AJAX, JavaScript)
- What is `PerformWaitCallback`?
- Why 7644 ms for only 1094 ms of work?

Comment: Are you measuring just *one* request?  You should start the app up and run *multiple* requests; there's inherent overhead involved in starting up the web application.

Comment: I "heat up" the app before profiling one request. I get similar results if I run multiple request (N x 8 sec).

Comment: Probably it depends on whether you are using IIS, IIS Express or Web Development Server.

Comment: This trace is made with WebDevServer.

Comment: for better testing use IIS,also there is a very useful memory profiler ANTS Profiler from RedGate, I prefer using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `PerformWaitCallback`, this is what the reference source has to say:

> Call back helper. This function dispatches requests to the
>   user-callbacks. The work-items are fetched from the per-appdomain
>   queue in a loop until either there is no more work or the quantum has
>   expired. The quantum is enforced to maintain fairness among
>   appdomains.

You can see the full code [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Threading/ThreadPool@cs/1305376/ThreadPool@cs).

BTW, I'm not sure if you'll see this in .NET 4.5 - again from the reference source (couldn't find an online version, you'll have to download it from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/):

```
//This type is necessary because VS 2010's debugger looks for a method named 
///_ThreadPoolWaitCallbacck.PerformWaitCallback 
//on the stack to determine if a thread is a ThreadPool thread or not.  
//We have a better way to do this for .NET 4.5, but
//still need to maintain compatibility with VS 2010.  
//When compat with VS 2010 is no longer an issue, this type may be removed.
internal static class _ThreadPoolWaitCallback
{ 
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    static internal bool PerformWaitCallback() 
    { 
        return ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why are there so many threads? (images resources, AJAX, JavaScript)

The web server creates a thread pool to manage incoming requests, and there are a number of threads in the pool.

> What is PerformWaitCallback?

Don't know for sure, but it looks like the code that waits for a thread pool thread to complete its task.

> Why 7644 ms for only 1094 ms of work?

It looks like the profiler is counting the time that some threads are spending waiting for new work. I haven't used dotTrace, but most profilers have a way to configure them so they can identify when threads are waiting vs. working -- based on the info you posted, I suspect the profiler isn't configured quite right.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but I was working off the performance issues. If I monitor IIS with DotTrace, there is no more `PerformWaitCallback`, but `System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32)` with same time differences...